# Characterisation of a good Reduction of a Curve (Silverman)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, elliptic-curves

I have following two questions to some steps in the proof of Prop. 5.5 (Chap. VII.5, p. 199) in Silverman's "Elliptic Curves":

At first here is the setting:

[image]

...and here the start of the proof...

[image]

The both questions are concerning the two tagged lines in the image below:

1. How we conclude from the given equation $256 (1 − \lambda(1 − \lambda))^3 − j\lambda^2(1 − \lambda)2 = 0$ and the integrality of j that $\lambda$ is in $R$ ?

My ideas: we assump that $char(k) \not = 2$ ...

2. Why is $j(E) \in R$ ?

Here the concerning page:

[image]